# Get current Highlight in VS Code Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am not talking about the current selection, which can be accessed by `vscode.window.activeTextEditor.selection`.

When the cursor is inside an identifier, variable name, etc, it becomes highlighted, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of VS Code]

What is this highlight object called? How do I access it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Searching for everything from "highlight" to "identifier" and whatever else, the answer was more obvious. `TextDocument` has a `getWordRangeAtPosition` method, which takes a position and returns the range of the word.

```js
const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
let cursorPosition = editor.selection.start;
let wordRange = editor.document.getWordRangeAtPosition(cursorPosition);
let highlight = editor.document.getText(wordRange);
// highlight will now contain the currently highlighted word
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think it uses the language grammar / syntax, it uses the "word pattern" of a language, which is a different thing.

Comment: @Gama11 I was pretty sure it did, but now I can't find the documentation for it. Took it out for now lest I spread false info.

Comment: Afaik, there actually isn't an API method that takes grammar tokenization into account yet: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/580

Comment: with the new api line number two should be replaced by [...editor.selections].pop().start;

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are showing is called a **[Document Highlight](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#highlight-all-occurrences-of-a-symbol-in-a-document)**. Other instances (of in this case `colorData`) will also be highlighted. The answer by @Rene Roth is probably answering what you want. And as @Gama11 wrote, using getWordRangeAtPosition without a second parameter uses the "word pattern" of a language. However a document highlight doesn't have to be a single word.

As far as I know you can't get a list of all the highlights? (I've only just figured them out for use in my first extension.)

To highlight like that you need to use `registerDocumentHighlightProvider` and [`provideDocumentHighlights`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentHighlightProvider). The `DocumentHighlightKind` can be used to provide different highlight colors (say when an instance of a highlighted variable is on the right or left of an equal sign, i.e. read or written, or for some other reason for distinction). I've used DocumentHighlightKind successfully to show a highlight that's contained within another.