# How to get highlighted text from VSCode Extension API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-api

I'm using the VSCode API to build an extension, but I've found no documentation that covers how to grab the user's highlighted text, such as that shown below:

[image]

There is a similar question [regarding the word the cursor is currently on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54373595/get-current-highlight-in-vs-code-extension), but I would like to grab the entirety of the highlighted text.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67310696/836330 it has more info about provding a Range to the `getText` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is a modified version of [Mark's answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67309142/check-value-of-last-line-selected-vscode-api/67310696#67310696)

```js
const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
const selection = editor.selection;
if (selection && !selection.isEmpty) {
    const selectionRange = new vscode.Range(selection.start.line, selection.start.character, selection.end.line, selection.end.character);
    const highlighted = editor.document.getText(selectionRange);
}
```

Comment: In the linked case they only wanted the last line of a selection.  But in your case, `const selectionRange = new vscode.Range(selection.start, selection.end);` is probably sufficient.  And no need for the `firstSelectedCharacter ` variable.

Comment: @Mark just updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the active text editor using the `activeTextEditor` API call and then use the `selections` field to get your selection ranges. Your code would look something like this:

```
let editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor
let selections = editor.selections
```

VSCode API Docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditor