# How to access highlighted text with VSCode extension API?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-api

There was an almost identically worded question asked to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73043106/how-to-get-highlighted-text-from-vscode-extension-api), but when they said highlighted, they actually meant selected. What I want is *highlighted* text, as shown in both div tags here: [image: highlighting].

I've read through the docs but I can't find this anywhere.